# Validate custom fields in wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type `speaker` and in speaker I have a custom field `speaker_organization`. How can I validate this and display error in `admin notice`.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'speaker_organization_box' );
function speaker_organization_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'speaker_organization',
        __( 'Organization', 'dbem' ),
        'speaker_organization_box_content',
        'speaker',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}

function speaker_organization_box_content( $post ) {
    // generate a nonce field
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'dbem-speaker-organization-nonce' );

    // get previously saved meta values (if any)
    $speaker_organization = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'speaker_organization', true );

    echo '<label for="speaker_organization"></label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="speaker_organization" name="speaker_organization" placeholder="Organization Name" value="'.$speaker_organization.'" />';
}

function speaker_organization_box_save( $post_id ) {
  $speaker_organization = $_POST['speaker_organization'];
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'speaker_organization', $speaker_organization ); 
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'speaker_organization_box_save' );
```

Comment: You might want to check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/validated-field-for-acf/

Answer (score 5):

using

> add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );

or using validate js

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_js');   
function add_my_js(){    
  wp_enqueue_script('my_validate', 'path/to/jquery.validate.min.js', array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script('my_script_js', 'path/to/my_script.js');
}

jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery("#post").validate();
});

<input type="text" name="my_custom_text_field" class="required"/>
```

---

```
function wpse_update_post_custom_values($post_id, $post) {
    // Do some checking...
    if($_POST['subhead'] != 'value i expect') {
        // Add an error here
        $errors->add('oops', 'There was an error.');
    }
    return $errors;
} 
add_action('save_post','wpse_update_post_custom_values',1,2);
```

[validate js code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/validating-custom-meta-box-values-required-fields)

[using condition + admin notice](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63384/how-to-validate-custom-fields-in-custom-post-type)